# Introduces to cycle in the graph

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pom.xml

I have two modules and one parent in my application.
- parent
- module A (with classA1 and classA2)
- module B (with classB1 and classB2)

I need to use classA1&2 in the module B and classB1&2 in the module A.
I know want is a the cyclical exception but how can I try to do what I want...

`parent: pom.xml`

```
<modules>
    <module>../moduleA</module>
    <module>../moduleB</module>
</modules>
```

`moduleA: pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`moduleB: pom.xml`

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to either extract some common part from A and B to a separate module, or combine modules A and B into a single module.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a third module containing these two classes and use it in both modules.